# Trying to use loader animation to buy my webpage some time to load, but webpage still only loads after animation and in chunks

Tags: javascript, html, css, loader

I am attempting to make a website that utilizes a loader animation in the beginning to buy the "bulk" of my website some time to load. I set the loader animation to 3 seconds and my `<body>` element to be displayed as hidden. However, when the 3-second loader animation is done, my website still loads in chunks.

The code listed below has the exact code I am using, however the `<body>` is reduced to one simple sentence for sake of this thread. I am actually using an html/css/js/bootstrap template with pictures, favicons and other things. It isn't that heavy of a site, but there is a good bulk of media on there.

[Codepen link here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jywGMW)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .cssload-container *, .cssload-container *:before, .cssload-container *:after{
        box-sizing: border-box;
            -o-box-sizing: border-box;
            -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .cssload-container {
        margin: auto;
        width: 68px;
        height: 29px;
        position: fixed; /* or absolute */
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
    }
    .cssload-container > div {
        float: left;
        background: rgb(185,108,255);
        height: 100%;
        width: 5px;
        margin-right: 1px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .cssload-container .cssload-shaft1 {
        animation-delay: 0.06s;
            -o-animation-delay: 0.06s;
            -ms-animation-delay: 0.06s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 0.06s;
            -moz-animation-delay: 0.06s;
    }
    .cssload-container .cssload-shaft2 {
        animation-delay: 0.12s;
            -o-animation-delay: 0.12s;
            -ms-animation-delay: 0.12s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 0.12s;
            -moz-animation-delay: 0.12s;
    }
    .cssload-container .cssload-shaft3 {
        animation-delay: 0.17s;
            -o-animation-delay: 0.17s;
            -ms-animation-delay: 0.17s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 0.17s;
            -moz-animation-delay: 0.17s;
    }
    .cssload-container .cssload-shaft4 {
        animation-delay: 0.23s;
            -o-animation-delay: 0.23s;
            -ms-animation-delay: 0.23s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 0.23s;
            -moz-animation-delay: 0.23s;
    }
    .cssload-container .cssload-shaft5 {
        animation-delay: 0.29s;
            -o-animation-delay: 0.29s;
            -ms-animation-delay: 0.29s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 0.29s;
            -moz-animation-delay: 0.29s;
    }
    .cssload-container .cssload-shaft6 {
        animation-delay: 0.35s;
            -o-animation-delay: 0.35s;
            -ms-animation-delay: 0.35s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 0.35s;
            -moz-animation-delay: 0.35s;
    }
    .cssload-container .cssload-shaft7 {
        animation-delay: 0.4s;
            -o-animation-delay: 0.4s;
            -ms-animation-delay: 0.4s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
            -moz-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    }
    .cssload-container .cssload-shaft8 {
        animation-delay: 0.46s;
            -o-animation-delay: 0.46s;
            -ms-animation-delay: 0.46s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 0.46s;
            -moz-animation-delay: 0.46s;
    }
    .cssload-container .cssload-shaft9 {
        animation-delay: 0.52s;
            -o-animation-delay: 0.52s;
            -ms-animation-delay: 0.52s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 0.52s;
            -moz-animation-delay: 0.52s;
    }
    .cssload-container .cssload-shaft10 {
        animation-delay: 0.58s;
            -o-animation-delay: 0.58s;
            -ms-animation-delay: 0.58s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 0.58s;
            -moz-animation-delay: 0.58s;
    }

    .cssload-container {
        height: 39px;
    }
    .cssload-container > div {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 34px;
        height: 5px;
        animation: cssload-wave 1.73s infinite ease-in-out;
            -o-animation: cssload-wave 1.73s infinite ease-in-out;
            -ms-animation: cssload-wave 1.73s infinite ease-in-out;
            -webkit-animation: cssload-wave 1.73s infinite ease-in-out;
            -moz-animation: cssload-wave 1.73s infinite ease-in-out;
    }
    .cssload-container .shaft1 {
        animation-delay: -1.73s;
            -o-animation-delay: -1.73s;
            -ms-animation-delay: -1.73s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: -1.73s;
            -moz-animation-delay: -1.73s;
    }
    .cssload-container .shaft2 {
        animation-delay: -1.61s;
            -o-animation-delay: -1.61s;
            -ms-animation-delay: -1.61s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: -1.61s;
            -moz-animation-delay: -1.61s;
    }
    .cssload-container .shaft3 {
        animation-delay: -1.5s;
            -o-animation-delay: -1.5s;
            -ms-animation-delay: -1.5s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: -1.5s;
            -moz-animation-delay: -1.5s;
    }
    .cssload-container .shaft4 {
        animation-delay: -1.38s;
            -o-animation-delay: -1.38s;
            -ms-animation-delay: -1.38s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: -1.38s;
            -moz-animation-delay: -1.38s;
    }
    .cssload-container .shaft5 {
        animation-delay: -1.27s;
            -o-animation-delay: -1.27s;
            -ms-animation-delay: -1.27s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: -1.27s;
            -moz-animation-delay: -1.27s;
    }
    .cssload-container .shaft6 {
        animation-delay: -1.15s;
            -o-animation-delay: -1.15s;
            -ms-animation-delay: -1.15s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: -1.15s;
            -moz-animation-delay: -1.15s;
    }
    .cssload-container .shaft7 {
        animation-delay: -1.04s;
            -o-animation-delay: -1.04s;
            -ms-animation-delay: -1.04s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: -1.04s;
            -moz-animation-delay: -1.04s;
    }
    .cssload-container .shaft8 {
        animation-delay: -0.92s;
            -o-animation-delay: -0.92s;
            -ms-animation-delay: -0.92s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: -0.92s;
            -moz-animation-delay: -0.92s;
    }
    .cssload-container .shaft9 {
        animation-delay: -0.81s;
            -o-animation-delay: -0.81s;
            -ms-animation-delay: -0.81s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: -0.81s;
            -moz-animation-delay: -0.81s;
    }
    .cssload-container .shaft10 {
        animation-delay: -0.69s;
            -o-animation-delay: -0.69s;
            -ms-animation-delay: -0.69s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: -0.69s;
            -moz-animation-delay: -0.69s;
    }
    .cssload-container .shaft11 {
        animation-delay: -0.58s;
            -o-animation-delay: -0.58s;
            -ms-animation-delay: -0.58s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: -0.58s;
            -moz-animation-delay: -0.58s;
    }



    @keyframes cssload-wave {
        50% {
            height: 100%;
            margin-top: 0;
            background: rgb(86,215,198);
        }
    }

    @-o-keyframes cssload-wave {
        50% {
            height: 100%;
            margin-top: 0;
            background: rgb(86,215,198);
        }
    }

    @-ms-keyframes cssload-wave {
        50% {
            height: 100%;
            margin-top: 0;
            background: rgb(86,215,198);
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes cssload-wave {
        50% {
            height: 100%;
            margin-top: 0;
            background: rgb(86,215,198);
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes cssload-wave {
        50% {
            height: 100%;
            margin-top: 0;
            background: rgb(86,215,198);
        }
    }

h2 {
  position: fixed; /* or absolute */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">

    <div id="loader">
        <div class="cssload-container">
        <div class="cssload-shaft1"></div>
        <div class="cssload-shaft2"></div>
        <div class="cssload-shaft3"></div>
        <div class="cssload-shaft4"></div>
        <div class="cssload-shaft5"></div>
        <div class="cssload-shaft6"></div>
        <div class="cssload-shaft7"></div>
        <div class="cssload-shaft8"></div>
        <div class="cssload-shaft9"></div>
        <div class="cssload-shaft10"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
      <h2>Zing! If you're seeing this after the loader animation, it works!</h2>
    </div>

    <script>
    var myVar;

    function myFunction() {
        myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
    }

    function showPage() {
      document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "inline";
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of guessing when your content is ready to be viewed you can attach an event handler to the document to listen for `DOMContentLoaded` then call your `showPage()` function within that. Like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  showPage();
});
```

Comment: The problem I am experiencing in my current code is that the actual webpage won't load until after the loader animation is done, regardless if I set it to one second, two seconds, three seconds or ten seconds.

Comment: The codepen had a very mild string of text for example purposes, which I imagine was a lot easier to load versus what I had mentioned in the original thread that I'm loading an entire website that has bootstrap and other various front-end frameworks. I'm actually using a webpage template such as this one http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page208/build